# Validating decimal scale in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I have the following model:

```
class Logo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true,  length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :price, presence: true, 
    numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validates :stitch_count, presence: true,
    numericality: { greater_than: 0, only_integer: true }
end
```

Every logo has a price. I want to validate the scale of the price. It must accept the following:
[10.44, 12.1, 16] and reject the following: [10.123, 13.11111, 16.123], as these are obviously not valid prices. I've tried validating by format using the following regex: `/\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/`, which, according to another poster on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517013/price-validation-for-rails-4), validates for at most 2 decimal places. It doesn't work. Another poster on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098990/ruby-rails-how-can-you-validate-against-decimal-scale) pointed out that the number of decimal places only matters when the value is a string, and that by the time the validator runs, it's no longer a string. His suggestions, as well as a few more, don't work. So how would I run a regex on a decimal? You would think Rails would have something to validate if a number is a valid price or not.

I run the following test:

```
  def setup
    @logo = Logo.new(name: "ASG Security", price: 12, stitch_count: 15000, note: "Ali")
  end

  test "price scale must be less than 2" do
    @logo.price = 14.995
    assert_not @logo.valid?
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money), which I've used, or maybe try [this rails wrapper](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) for it which provides premade money validations.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not a good idea to use decimals for currencies.

If you're using USD, you can make the attribute `price_cents` instead of `price`.

*For example:*

Rather than passing `1.23` as price, you would pass `123` as price_cents.

And echoing what @chad_ mentioned, it's a good idea to use the Money gem. (Additionally the Money gem will expect currencies as "cents")

Answer (score 0):

By the time the validation runs, the price is no longer a `String`. You can verify that a number has at most two decimals by comparing `price` with `price.round(2)`:

```rb
10.44  == 10.44.round(2)   # true
10.123 == 10.123.round(2)  # false
```

You can write a [custom validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) that makes this comparison and adds an error to the attribute in case it is not equal.

Comment: It's usually risky to compare floats with `==`, but this seems to work fine for reasonably large numbers. `123456789012345678.12` fails for example, but I'm not sure if it's a problem.